# Trouble binding command to button in WPF

Tags: wpf, command, mvvm

I've got a button in a ribbon I've implemented and having trouble binding to a command. The ribbon is in a UserControl named AppRibbon. The AppRibon control has a public property called SelectedModule which has a property named RenameModuleCmd. When I create an event handler for the button, i call the command explicitly to make sure everything is working as shown below:

```
  public partial class ApplicationRibbon : UserControl {
    public ApplicationRibbon() {
      InitializeComponent();
    }

    public ModuleViewModel SelectedModule { get; set; }

    private void ButtonTool_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
      SelectedModule.RenameModuleCmd.Execute(null);
    }
  }
```

This works fine. But I obviously don't want to use the code behind model... much rather use the Command binding. So I tried the folling bindings, but nothing fired the command.

```
<... Command="{Binding Path=SelectedModule.RenameModuleCmd}" />
<... Command="{Binding Path=AppRibbon.SelectedModule.RenameModuleCmd}" />
```

I can't figure out why these won't work. I've set breakpoints on the command's CanExecute and Execute methods as well on the RenameModuleCmd property's getter, but none are hit. Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify what element you're binding to when developing a UserControl and binding inside it. Try:

```
<... Command="{Binding ElementName=AppRibbon, Path=SelectedModule.RenameModuleCmd}" />
```

Assuming your UserControl is named AppRibbon as your post seems to imply.

Comment: Thanks JustABill, but I was doing this within the UserControl where SelectedModule is defined. Thus I didn't think that the ElementName was relevant. I don't have the app handy to test this, but I suspect it won't make a change.

Comment: That seems intuitive, but trust me, you can't bind to a property of a UserControl (or a Window, or any other 'outermost' element for that matter) unless you pass an ElementName or the DataContext is already set. If you've done the latter, then I just misread and I apologize.

Comment: I just verified the name (<UserControl x:Name="Ribbon">) and then added this as the binding: Command="{Binding ElementName=Ribbon, Path=SelectedModule.RenameModuleCmd}"

The Ribbon UserControl has a public property of SelectedModule which is of type ModuleViewModel which contains public property of type ICommand named RenameModuleCmd. I set breakpoints in the getter and unfortunately nothing happens. However in that same button if I add a click handler that does the following, I get the desired behavior (prefer to avoid events tho): SelectedModule.RenameModuleCmd.Execute(null); 

Ideas?

Comment: I'd suggest you look at http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=52 for how to see where your binding is failing. If it doesn't show up there, I really don't know. Maybe implement INotifyPropertyChanged?